# Prove that $(a+b)(b+c)(c+d)(d+a)\geq(a+1)(b+1)(c+1)(d+1)$

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Question:

> Let $a, b, c, d$ be positive real numbers satisfying $abcd=1$. Prove that $(a+b)(b+c)(c+d)(d+a)\geq(a+1)(b+1)(c+1)(d+1)$. Characterise the instances of equality.

My (failed) approach:
I immediately noticed that equality holds when $a=b=c=d=1$ and thought of using AM-GM Inequality.
I tried $(a+b)(b+c)(c+d)(d+a)\geq16abcd=16$ (By applying AM-GM Inequality on each term). Hence, it suffices to prove $16\geq(a+1)(b+1)(c+1)(d+1)$, but this is not true, and I got stuck. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Solution on AoPS: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h217874p1207401

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plan is to show:

$$\frac{(a + 1)(b + 1)(c + 1)(d + 1)}{(a+b)(b+c)(c + d)(d+a)} \leq 1$$

We first split up the expression in a way that is more suitable for AM-GM:

$$\frac{(a + 1)(b + 1)(c + 1)(d + 1)}{(a+b)(b+c)(c + d)(d+a)} = \frac{(a+1)(b+1)}{(a+b)}  \frac{(c+1)(d+1)}{(c+d)}  \frac{1}{(b+c)(d+a)}$$

Now taking a look at the single $\frac{(a+1)(b+1)}{(a+b)}$ part, we can apply AM-GM ($a + b \geq 2\sqrt{ab}$):

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{(a+1)(b+1)}{(a+b)} &= \frac{ab + a + b + 1}{a + b} \\
                         &= \frac{ab}{a+b} + 1 + \frac{1}{a + b}\\
                         &\leq \frac{ab}{2\sqrt{ab}} + 1 + \frac{1}{2\sqrt{ab}} \\
                         &= \frac{ab + 2\sqrt{ab} + 1}{2\sqrt{ab}} \\
                         &= \frac{\left(\sqrt{ab} + 1\right)^2}{2\sqrt{ab}} \\
\end{align*}$$

Now, we plug this into our main equation:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{(a+1)(b+1)}{(a+b)} \frac{(c+1)(d+1)}{(c+d)} \frac{1}{(b+c)(d+a)} &\leq \frac{\left(\sqrt{ab} + 1\right)^2}{2\sqrt{ab}} \frac{\left(\sqrt{cd} + 1\right)^2}{2\sqrt{cd}}  \frac{1}{(b+c)(d+a)} \\ 
&= \frac{\left(\sqrt{ab} + 1\right)^2 \left(\sqrt{cd} + 1\right)^2}{4\sqrt{ab}\sqrt{cd}(b+c)(d+a)} \\
&= \frac{\left(\sqrt{ab} + 1\right)^2 \left(\sqrt{cd} + 1\right)^2}{4(b+c)(d+a)}
\end{align*}$$

Then using Cauchy-Schwarz: $$|\vec{p}||\vec{q}| \geq |\vec{p} \cdot \vec{q}|^2 \implies (p_x^2 + p_y^2)(q_x^2 + q_y^2) \geq (p_x q_x + p_y q_y)^2$$

On the denominator $(b + c)(d + a)$ to get:

$$(b + c)(d + a) = (\sqrt{b}^2 + \sqrt{c}^2)(\sqrt{a}^2 + \sqrt{d}^2) \geq (\sqrt{ab} + \sqrt{cd})^2$$

Therefore we can decrease the denominator and get:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{\left(\sqrt{ab} + 1\right)^2 \left(\sqrt{cd} + 1\right)^2}{4(b+c)(d+a)} &\leq \frac{\left(\sqrt{ab} + 1\right)^2\left(\sqrt{cd} + 1\right)^2}{4(\sqrt{ab} + \sqrt{cd})^2} \\
&= \frac{1}{4} \left( \frac{\left(\sqrt{ab} + 1\right) \left(\sqrt{cd} + 1\right)}{(\sqrt{ab} + \sqrt{cd})} \right)^2 \\
&= \frac{1}{4} \left( \frac{ \sqrt{abcd} + \sqrt{ab} + \sqrt{cd} + 1 }{\sqrt{ab} + \sqrt{cd}} \right)^2 \\
&= \frac{1}{4} \left( \frac{ \sqrt{1} + 1 }{\sqrt{ab} + \sqrt{cd}} 
 + 1\right)^2 \\
&= \frac{1}{4} \left( \frac{ 2 }{\sqrt{ab} + \sqrt{cd}} 
 + 1\right)^2  \\
&= \frac{1}{4} \left( \frac{ 2 }{2\sqrt[4]{abcd}} 
 + 1\right)^2  \text{ by AM-GM again} \\
&= \frac{1}{4} \left( 1
 + 1\right)^2  \leq 1
\end{align*}$$

Comment: in the third to last line, you are decreasing both the numerator and denominator and that does not necessarily result in an increase.

Comment: @dezdichado Ah yep whoops! Fixed it rn. Thanks!

Comment: Side note: (per the AOPS link) The key was $(x+1)(y+1)/(xy) \leq (1  + \sqrt{xy})^2 / (2\sqrt{xy})$. You showed it at the top for $ x = a , y = b$. You can apply this again at the end for $x = \sqrt{ab}, y = \sqrt{cd}$ to reach the conclusion immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a+b+c+d=4u$, $ab+ac+ad+bc+bd+cd=6v^2,$ where $v>0$, $abc+abd+acd+bcd=4w^3$ and $abcd=t^4,$ where $t>0$.

Thus, since $$\prod_{cyc}(a+b)-\sum_{cyc}a\sum_{cyc}abc=(ac-bd)^2\geq0,$$ it's enough to prove that:
$$16uw^3\geq\prod_{cyc}(a+1)$$ or
$$8uw^3\geq t^4+2ut^3+3v^2t^2+2w^3t,$$
which is true because by Maclaurin $u\geq v\geq w\geq t$ and by Rolle $w^6\geq v^2t^4.$

Comment: $(a+b)(b+c)(c+d)(d+a) - (a+b+c)(abc+bcd+cda+dab) = (ac-bd)^2$ is nice. The resulting inequality $ (a+b+c)(abc+bcd+cda+dab) \ge (a+1)(b+1)(c+1)(d+1)$ is symmetric (the original one is not).

Comment: @River Li You can see that it's very not strong.

Comment: Yes. But for symmetric, we can use pqr. Ah, some typos in my comment, $a+b+c$ should be $a + b + c + d$.

Comment: @River Li I think the following is interesting enough. Let $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ and $e$ be positives such that $abcde=1$. Prove that $\prod\limits_{cyc}(a+b)\geq\prod\limits_{cyc}(a+1).$

Comment: Yes, interesting.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg For the 5 variables inequality, in the [AOPS link](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h217874p1207401), didn't Ji Chen show that it is not true for $a=b=c=x^2, d=e=1/x^3$ and $ x> 8, x < 1/8$?

Comment: @Calvin Lin Thank you! I forgot about this link. In this link there is  another  my conjecture.